# How to pass control of a GUI to a different class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have never done multithreading (which I think is what I need, but I'm not sure), and don't really understand how, which I think will be apparent by the end of this question ...

I have made a GUI in Java with JButtons and such, and when the user clicks on a specific button, I want to pass control of the GUI to a different class, so that the 2nd class can alter/update the GUI. Then, after the user clicks on a different button (put on the GUI by the 2nd class), it will return control of the GUI to the first class.

This is what I have tried, but it does not behave correctly:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Addition implements ActionListener
{
public JFrame window;
public JPanel windowContents;
public JTextArea windowDialog;
public JButton[] buttons;
public int i = 1;

public Subtraction subtract;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new Addition();
        }
    });
}

Addition ()
{
    window = new JFrame();
    windowContents = new JPanel();
    windowDialog = new JTextArea();
    buttons = new JButton[2];
    buttons[0] = new JButton();
    buttons[1] = new JButton();
    subtract = new Subtraction();

    window.setSize(300, 300);
    windowDialog.setText("Click on a button below. The current value is " + i);
    buttons[0].setText("Click me to add 1");
    buttons[1].setText("Click me to change control");
    buttons[0].addActionListener(this);
    buttons[1].addActionListener(this);

    windowContents.add(windowDialog);
    windowContents.add(buttons[0]);
    windowContents.add(buttons[1]);

    window.add(windowContents);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public void updateGUI()
{
    windowDialog.setText("Click on a button below. The current value is " + i);
    windowDialog.revalidate();
    windowDialog.repaint();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

{
    if(e.getSource() == buttons[0])
    {
        i = i + 1;
        updateGUI();
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == buttons[1])
    {
        subtract.getGUI(window, windowContents, buttons, windowDialog, i);
        subtract.takeControl();

        while(subtract.done == false)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Final int = " + i);
    }
}

}
```

And for the 2nd class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Subtraction implements ActionListener
{
public JFrame window;
public JPanel windowContents;
public JTextArea windowDialog;
public JButton[] buttons;
public int i;
public boolean done;

public void getGUI(JFrame window, JPanel windowContents, JButton[] buttons, JTextArea windowDialog, int i)
{
    this.window = window;
    this.windowContents = windowContents;
    this.windowDialog = windowDialog;
    this.buttons = buttons;
    this.i = i;
}

public void takeControl()
{
    done = false;
    buttons[0].setText("Click me to subtract 1");
    buttons[1].setText("Click me to change control back to addition");
    updateGUI();
}

public void updateGUI()
{
    windowDialog.setText("Click on a button below. The current value is " + i);
    windowDialog.revalidate();
    windowDialog.repaint();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == buttons[0])
    {
        i = i - 1;
        updateGUI();
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == buttons[2])
    {
        done = true;
    }
}
}
```

When I run this the GUI freezes  on the line

```
if(e.getSource == buttons[1]) //From the Addition Class
```

so I never get an updated GUI when I call updateGUI() from the OtherClass.

Note: I copied the UpdateGUI() method from my first class, and it works perfectly there, so I know the method works. It's just that the screen doesn't actually change.

Note 2: I know that this code could be done much better through just 1 class called "Math" or something like that, but this isn't my actual project. My actual project is over 1000 lines long and the GUI does need to be handled by 2 classes. In order not to burden readers with 1000+ lines of code, I have made a simple program that behaves the same way, just to illustrate what happens and what the problem is.

Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: Have a look at "SwingWorker". Implement your "doStuff" method into "doInBackground()" method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: You really should get rid of that while loop!

Comment: Don't do `while(OtherClass.done == false)` within the EDT for starters

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: If I get rid of the while loop the code flies through the OtherClass code and goes right to the //FirstClass does more stuff line. I want the FirstClass to STOP doing stuff until the OtherClass basically says "Ok. I'm done. You can resume FirstClass"

Comment: *"I created a much more simplified version for the purposes of asking the question."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: As per your suggestion Andrew, I have edited the question to have a ... I think it's now a SSCCE. The code in the question now is fully written and able to be compiled, so it should lend itself easier to understand the issue. My apologies for being vague and incomplete before.

Comment: No it will freeze here -> `while(subtract.done == false)` and here -> `Thread.sleep(1000);`, Swing is single threaded, you've blocked the Event Dispatching Thread preventing it from EVER responding to new UI events